# Error when logging in using CakePHP's Auth component

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.3

I've integrated Cake's Auth component into my app. It mostly seems to work ok but I quite often get an error when logging in looking something like this:

> Error: Call to undefined method Security::getDataSource()
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ips-mvc\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php
>   Line: 1063

Any idea what this means?

For the record, I do have a model in my app called `Security`. I wasn't aware of any reserved model names in Cake but is there a chance my `Security` mdoel is conflicting with a Cake component? This error can still occur when the `Security` model is not used although it is quite sporadic in its appearance - sometimes refreshing the page will make everything work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I went ahead and changed my `Security` model to another name and the problem seems to have solved itself now but an explanation would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by passing a component instance to a method expecting a model instance, and are easily avoidable by not creating model classes with the same name as a component in use.

### Models and Components cannot have the same name

The problem is not related to duplicate class names as Models do not have a class name suffix, yet components do.

However, for example, in a controller the following syntax:

```
$this->{$alias}
```

Is used to access *both* a component (class name `{$alias}Component`) *or* a model (class name `$alias`).

As such, having a model with the same name as a component makes one or the other inaccessible.

### Cache Poisoning

However the problem doesn't stop there. Objects are stored [in the class registry](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php#L203) using an alias as the key:

For example, in [Model](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L702):

```
 ClassRegistry::addObject($this->alias, $this);
```

If the same alias is used (Security model, `SecurityComponent`) - the object occupying the key "Security" is simply the first one to get added to the registry - all subsequent requests for "Security" will return that object.

Depending on cache expiration and whether the model and component are used in the same request - determines how often errors such as the one in the question appear and whether they are "random" or reproducible.